# Can't find a way to cast a char into u8

Tags: rust

I've been trying to replace every letter in a given string slice with its position in the alphabet ("A" with "1", "B" with "2" etc).

```rust
fn alphabet_position(text: &str) -> String {
    let s = text
        .chars()
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|&c| c.is_alphabetic())
        .map(|c| c.to_ascii_uppercase())
        .map(|c| c as u8)
        .map(|c| (c - 64u8) as char)
        .collect();
    s
}
```

Comment: Instead of magical numbers like 64, why not base that off of `'A'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [`u8::to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#method.to_string) function.

```rust
fn alphabet_position(text: &str) -> String {
    let s = text
        .chars()
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|&c| c.is_alphabetic())
        .map(|c| c.to_ascii_uppercase())
        .map(|c| c as u8)
        .map(|c| (c - 64u8).to_string())
        .collect();
    s
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9630d6bea5c72bb13bc61dca9b19ed09)